# Cargar array con listado de números de un .txt

Tags: java, array

Buen día estimada comunidad, h eintentado llenar un arreglo de tipo int con datos que tengo en un .txt en mi ordenador.
Me están generando errores al momento de intentar insertar; alguien sabe cómo se pueden insertar los datos?
Gracias
Comparto el código que llevo ...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class PruebaSeries {
//Instances

//Atributes
int[] randomList;

//Functions
public BufferedReader readFile(String fileUbication) {
    //local instances
    FileReader read = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    //function
    try {
        File archive = new File(fileUbication); //Load file
        //Exist validation
        int loadTries = 3;// cont tries
        while (!archive.exists() && loadTries > 0) {
                System.out.println("El archivo no existe o la ruta está mal escrita\nPor favor validar la información,\nle quedan " +loadTries+ " intentos");
                loadTries --;
        }
        read = new FileReader(fileUbication); // FileReader object load
        br = new BufferedReader(read); //load BF object with read file          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //Exceptions controller
    }       
    return null;
}

public void loadArray(String fileUbication) {
    //local instances
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        //function
        br = readFile(fileUbication);
        String line = br.readLine();//read first line
        while(line != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                randomList[i] = ;               }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
}

}
```

Comment: Buenas. ¿ Que error te da ?.

Answer (score 1):

Veo varios errores en el código aunque tendrías que poner dónde te falla exactamente. Revisa lo siguiente:

- La variable randomList no está inicializada cuando la empiezas a usar
- Además, randomList[i] = ; es un error. Imagino que debería ser randomList[i] = values[i]; aunque con eso no será suficiente ya que si hay más de una línea te machacará el contenido y solo guardará la última
- Estos errores se dan en la función loadArray pero no veo que la estés llamando mientras que la función readFile devuelve siempre nulo, haya encontrado o no el fichero a leer

En general, veo el código desorganizado y sin mucha utilidad conforme lo has puesto. Arregla lo que puedas y lo vuelves a poner junto al mensaje de error que te dé